Why does the FreeRoute autorouter get caught in an endless loop?
I made the FreeRoute 1.3.1 autorouter route the following two-layer PCB I had made with KiCad 6.0.11:

Unfortunately, the autorouter apparently gets caught in an endless loop after some 15 minutes. It starts jumping between the white connection visible in the followig screenshot:

…and the pads right below the white line. The pass counter gets incremented every 2", and the to_route counter runs to 30 and then gets reset to zero. The failed counter on the far right also gets incremented and then zeroed out. There is no escape from this loop, not even after several hours or after stopping and restarting the process. Why?

Why not ask about it in KiCad forums if that is a KiCad supported autorouter? Also that FreeRoute version is 3 to 5 years old now, and that KiCad is about 2 years old now.

Sorry, I am not trying to be rude. Just saying you are using old software and newer KiCad may work better with the autorouter that has not been updated for many years. Have you tried newer KiCad? Also why the autorouter gets stuck is not necessarily an electrical engineering problem, but a software engineering issue in KiCad or the autorouter. Which is why you might solve the problem quicker by asking directly on KiCad forums where also KiCad developers may be able to answer your question.

I'd be surprised if any autorouter gives satisfactory results with such a densely populated board.

It seems this software still has some bugs in it.
https://github.com/freerouting/freerouting/issues
If it cannot create a solution and doesn't give up, that tells me you may need to orient some connectors that cross too many lines or add a layer.  Visualize the traces on one side being orthogonal to most of the ones on the other side by repositioning the ICs and connectors and see if you can get a better response.
Alternatively, use micropitch connectors that leave more room for traces and consider a smaller track/gap pitch.

I've just added two layers in KiCad, re-exported everything and gave FrteeRouter another try. But: No use!

I solved the issue (I'd rather call it a design flaw than a bug) by putting the endless loop of the autorouter to an end, saving the session file, importing it into Kicad and doing the rest by hand. What did help a bit, yet did not solve the endless loop issue itself, was to add two copper layers and to reduce the thickness of some conductive rails. The culprit, BTW, was one of the ICs with a 0.4 mm pitch (U3 on the screenshot). This, of course, caused a maze of conductive rails and vias the autorouter was no longer able to cope with:

